# WHMCS Bulk Pricing Updater

Tags: web-hosting, php, bugs, whmcs

Their is a Bulk Pricing Updater addon in WHMCS which works well to update hosting accounts pricing but I am unable to update the domain pricing through that every time it gives this message

> Updated Domains with TLD 0 - 0 Affected

I have Google searched the problem and it seems a known issue which has yet to be addressed by WHMCS. In the meantime is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Can you please explain more? What you do and what happens?

Comment: Two suggestions were posted on the [WHMCS forums](http://forum.whmcs.com/showthread.php?76991-Can-t-get-Bulk-Pricing-Updater-to-work/page2) after you posted this question.

Answer (score 1):

The [WHMCS forums](http://forum.whmcs.com/showthread.php?76991-Can-t-get-Bulk-Pricing-Updater-to-work/page2) have a couple of suggestions.

[9DollarDomains](http://forum.whmcs.com/member.php?8528-9DollarDomains&s=e3ecf25fc459a3da49b70e346472d4f0) says:

> Here are some examples of manual SQL Queries that should work as a work around until this is fixed by WHMCS.
>
> 1. This will set all you one year .com domains to renew at $12.99
>
>    ```
>    UPDATE tbldomains SET recurringamount = "12.99" WHERE domain like "%.com" AND registrationperiod = "1";
>    ```
> 2. This will set all your one year .net domains that are currently at $11.97, to a new renewal price of $13.49
>
>    ```
>    UPDATE tbldomains SET recurringamount = "13.49" WHERE recurringamount = "11.97" AND domain like "%.net" AND registrationperiod = "1";
>    ```

[dpatricio](http://forum.whmcs.com/member.php?77447-dpatricio&s=e3ecf25fc459a3da49b70e346472d4f0) says:

> Insted of touching database, which is dangerous, check this module instead:
>   http://www.whmcs.com/appstore/2590/Prices-AutoCalc.html